# Can I use the proximity sensor of the Apple Watch?

Tags: watchkit, proximity

I have a question: Can I use the proximity Sensor from the Apple Watch in XCode (Objective-C).

Thank you!

Comment: I've never touched an apple watch before, but with phones you should check out this http://iosdevelopertips.com/device/using-the-proximity-sensor.html.  From what I understand with the phones there isn't much you can do with the proximity sensor besides telling if it's a "Yes" or "No".  The watch may be a different story.  I hope this is of use. Although it might not be at all!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. [Here](https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler) is the most complete and regularly updated list of available or awaiting (like gyroscope) APIs on Watch. And there is nothing about the proximity sensor.